# Extend cable of USB hub

Tags: cables, usb-c, usb-hub

I bought a device recently which is a USB hub. It has multiple HDMI ports, multiple USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports, an Ethernet port, an SD card slot, etc. It is a beast. It connects to my laptop via a USB-C cable.

It does surprise me that we have a PCB in the laptop and a port (USB-C) that can transmit data for so many things via a single port on the laptop.

The USB-C cable is quite short. The hub looks something like this:

[image: marking gauge]

Is it possible to extend the USB-C cable without detrimental impact on the performance of this device?

Comment: In a word, no. It is a small miracle it works even for that distance, if it even works reliably, or at all, depending on the laptop. If you need a longer cable, buy one with longer cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking this as an electronic redesign/modification question. Questions asking for help on using consumer electronics would be off-topic here.

> Is it possible to extend the USB-C cable without detrimental impact on the performance of this device?

Hm. So, USB-C spec explicitly **forbids** USB-C extension cables, for good reason; signal integrity for USB 3.0 SS is hard, and so is for the DP/HDMI alternative modes. Adding a working extension cable has the potential to lead to hard-to-debug intermittent failures, or just complete failure to operate.

So, your only option would be to replace the cable from the point it enters the PCB, and hope the termination that probably was hand-fiddled until it worked reliably on a bunch of different hosts still works well enough.

You can, of course, use an active device, a USB hub, to extend at least the USB functionality of your hub. But that won't preserve the ability to transport HDMI as alternative mode, so you'd lose the ability to connect HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "detrimental impact". But the longer you want your cable to be, the less maximum speeds you will be able to achieve and more errors.

1. If the device was designed correctly, the cable's length has been measured that on its output it can handle the speeds of USB-C/USB-3 etc. If you want to increase the cable's length then these specifications might not be true anymore. For example the longer the cable, the larger the in series resistance, so instead of ~3.3V usb signals you might get 3.0V. This might not affect the USB's speed but it might be more susceptible to noise. Also the longer the cable the lower frequencies the USB can reach on its modulation. (USB uses frequency modulation to transmit data)
2. the USB hub probably has in series resistor on the data pins (some of the data pins maybe). These resistors are there so that the D+/D- have the correct differential impedance as defined by the USB specifications (90 ohms, I dont have the source for that right now, you can look it up) a reference [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/585732/what-value-series-resistor-should-i-use-for-usb-data-lines-when-two-ics-require). If you increase the length of the cable, these resistors might need to be reduced in value.
3. You need to use a proper USB-C rated cable if you want to extend the cable. This will guarantee you a correct impedance. You also might want to solder the new extended cable the same way the current cable is soldered (on the pcb or the internal connector they used in the HUB). This is better from cutting this cable and soldering the new one. Again, it will help having the same impedance throughout the cable.

Overall you can get away extending the cable, but you wont know if it will have any impedance or noise issues later on.